# A Farmer Named Todd Finds Himself In A Very Large Store

Tags: story-identification

I think this is a Clifford Simak story, but I'm having trouble tracing it;  Todd, a farmer, is working his fields on his tractor when he sees a new building under construction. A few weeks later, the building opens under a name like "The Emporium" and Todd, curious, goes in.  Can't recall much after that, apart from Todd having a difficult time leaving the store.
Any ideas?

Comment: About when did you read this? Ex: a month ago, a year ago, several years ago?

Comment: Are you sure about the name? I have a complete collection of Simak's stories as an ebook, which makes it easy to search it for _"Todd"_, but there are no matches.

Comment: Can you expound on the difficulty 'Todd' had on leaving the store?

Comment: In order- three decades or more; The name may not be correct; and not sure- it was written ambiguously, like the way people had trouble finding their cars in "High Rise"